# filter array based on another

Tags: swift, filter

I have two arrays, one an array of array of profiles and one of the section names:

```
var sections: [Array<Profile>] = [friends, contacts, other]
var sectionNames = ["Friends", "Contacts", "Other Users"]
```

How do I filter the names based on whether the sections are empty? I get an error when I try the code below:

```
sectionNames.filter { index, _ in
    sections[index].count > 0
}

Contextual closure type '(String) throws -> Bool' expect 1 argument, but two given
```

Comment: From an API design perspective, you would probably have a much easier time with this if you had a better data structure. I would make a `ProfileSection` struct, with a `heading: String` and `members: [Profile]`. Then you could just have `sections: [ProfileSection]`, and you could just filter out the ones that are empty: `sections.filter { $0.isEmpty }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` and `compactMap`:

```swift
let nonEmptySections = zip(sections, sectionNames).compactMap { $0.isEmpty ? nil : $1 }
```

Using `zip` has the advantage that you don't get crashes if the two arrays have different sizes. On the other hand, it can lead to subtle bugs.

I'd recommend that you use a data structure to model you data instead:

```swift
struct Section {
    let name: String
    let profiles: [Profile]
}
```

This should ease the way you process the sections in your app. And by using @Alexander's suggestion, you can add an `isEmpty` property to the struct, making it even easier to use

```swift
extension Section {
    var isEmpty: Bool { return profiles.isEmpty }
}

... later in the code

let nonEmptySections = sections.filter { !$0.isEmpty }
```

Comment: And then simplify the design even more by adding `var isEmpty: Bool { self.profiles.isEmpty }`, so you could just do `sections.filter { $0.isEmpty }`. Good stuff!

Comment: I did end up going with the struct as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
var ar1:[Array<Int>] = [[1,2],[3,4,],[],[5,6]]
var ar2 = [1,2,3,4]
ar2 = (0 ..< ar1.count).filter {ar1[$0].count > 0}.map {ar2[$0]}
print(ar2) // [1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: I very strongly recommend writing code like `0 ..< ar1.count`. It's errorprone, and doesn't work for slices or collections with non-integral indices. See https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md#for-i-in-0arraycount-